# C# Memory Use Discrepancy between two Machines

Tags: c#, performance, memory, amazon-ec2, garbage-collection

**Wrote a C# scraper. And analyzed the markup of 30K URLs to pull certain metrics from them.**

Run the same code on two machines:

- *my dev box with 4 core CPU, 8 logical processors and 32GB or RAM*. It used up to 300MB of RAM to the end. As I display the `WorkingSet` size, I could even see the GC kick in and lower memory use, then growing back again.
- *on a EC2 instance, same data but an instance with only 2 processors and 1.7GB of RAM*. Here it used 1.1GB or RAM and, when all threads concluded work, it went down to 300MB just like my local test.

RAM usage was checked with both `Environment.WorkingSet` and Task Manager. My NET speed is not negligible so I don't think it could affect things even if that Amazon instance might be a little faster. *(EC2 net performance differs per instance and this one is on the affordable side hence slower side.)*

> **Why this memory use discrepancy?** And can I somehow estimate before hand the memory use in C#?

My guess is that having a slower CPU in the cloud, the GC preferred to keep allocating more than cleaning up what was already used. But this is just my theory to excuse it's unexpected behavior, based on wishful thinking. Still, on my 32GB of RAM it could have used way more but it behaved. On 1.7GB of RAM it went all crazy using 1.1GB of it... I don't get it.

In C++ I just think of how many URLs I fetch at the same time, I think of 256KB average size + size of extracted data and I can tell, before hand, how much memory will be used quite precise. But this C# test left me wondering.

As I plan to release this tool in the wild... I don't feel comfortable taking over half the RAM especially on a lesser machine.

**UPDATE**: *Forgot to mention both machines are Windows 8. Actually one is 8.1 (local) and one Server 2012 (EC2 cloud) both with .NET 4.5.2.*

Comment: Windows 7 caches memory it thinks it needs to cache to maintain adequate performance levels, and on your flame-thrower machine the nominal performance benefits it could get by caching the same amount of memory might not matter, so it's probably not bothering with the caching.  When it matters, unused memory is wasted memory, which would explain the additional usage on the cloud machine.  In any case, the extra memory being cached is probably available anyway, if your application suddenly needs it.

Comment: Incidentally, it's probably easier for .NET to do a garbage collection on the flame thrower machine.  Since you can't really control how Windows allocates memory, when garbage collection takes place, or when the memory will be released for other uses, the notion that you're "taking over half the RAM" is misplaced.  If it still worries you, examine your program for evidence of excessive object creation and destruction, and focus on fixing that, so that less garbage collection is needed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's written very carefully with a C++ mindset. :) I fetch a page, pull some tags and finally lock and push some numbers and strings to a List<>. When it's done, it dumps the List<> to the SQLite DB, but only when everything is scraped and analyzed as an embedded file DB is HDD acces-level slow. Markup strings are no longer referenced after processed. No idea how I can control more than this. New to C#, feels like it's a black box. :)

Comment: Just the difference in OS can explain everything.  Let me guess: Server 2012 is on the flame thrower.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Actually that's in the cloud, EC2 instance. There's no point on having a server version on my local machine... :)

Comment: Hmm, maybe they got a little better at memory management in Windows 8.  I've never been completely comfortable with the way Windows 7 manages memory.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've held back on upgrading until 1 month ago. But Windows 8 confirmed what I always knew and heard from others. It's faster than Windows 7, quite a bit. It lacks a proper darn Start Menu and it's still hard to get used to those nasty tiles... but I've pinned everything I need. **In terms of performance, they've done things right. I mostly write memory intensive stuff in native C++ and I can feel it.**

Comment: That's good to know.  It's apparently still pretty easy to get to the traditional desktop, and there are some hacks out there that can make it look more like Windows 7.

Comment: A windows server's garbage collection is entirely different than a windows client's. You can't compare it.

Comment: @DavidLibido So you're saying that the .NET framework *(not Windows Server as Windows itself has nothing to do with GC, but the runtime)* has different garbage collection implementations for Windows 8 and 2012 even if I installed the same .NET Runtime on both?

Comment: Yes. I've done some research on it in the past. I can't provide you with a source because it was like two years ago, but I'm sure Google can help you out there.